# Why does my Phaser gradient disappear?

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a radial gradient that starts from a point and grows from there, a little like smoke filling a room. I started with this example:

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/bitmapdata/radial-gradient

And have been slowly tweaking it to meet my needs. My current issue is that when my tween stops running the entire thing disappears. Here's what I've got:

In the create function:

```
    this.radGrad = this.game.make.bitmapData(600, 600);
    this.radGrad.addToWorld();
    this.outerCircle = new Phaser.Circle(200, 200, 0);

    this.smokeTween = this.game.add.tween(this.outerCircle).to( { radius: 300 }, 5000, Phaser.Easing.Sinusoidal.Out, true);
```

In the update function:

```
    const grd = this.radGrad.context.createRadialGradient(200, 200, 0, this.outerCircle.x, this.outerCircle.y, this.outerCircle.radius);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent");

    this.radGrad.cls();
    this.radGrad.circle(this.outerCircle.x, this.outerCircle.y, this.outerCircle.radius, grd);
```